# How to add html tag inside ternary operator in astro

Tags: astrojs

in my Astro project

on *Header.astro* page , I want to display link on some condition

```
---

import { SITE_TITLE } from '../consts';
const isDay = false;
---

<h1>
    {isTrue? `Happy Day` : SITE_TITLE}
</h1>
```

this works fine , but when add **<a>** tag in other condition inside

tried

```
{isTrue? `Happy Day` : <a href="https://www.somewhere.com">{SITE_TITLE}</a>}
```

it gives error

ReferenceError: SITE_TITLE is not defined

even tried with double curly `{{SITE_TITLE}}` but didnt work.

so my question is

How to add tag inside ternary in .astro file?

note: alternative way is to create a separate component and use it here is a separate things.

Comment: i would try `{isTrue? 'Happy Day' : '<a href="https://www.somewhere.com">' + SITE_TITLE + '</a>'}` ..but i never heard of astro, maybe the plus signs arent needed xD

Answer (score -1):

solved it.

added import solve the issue when writing html tag

```js
import { SITE_TITLE } from '../consts';
```

actually its my vs code format settings

```js
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
```

causing this issue

which auto remove unused import while saving the file after removing {SITE_TITLE} in file for once, moreover to that vs code not giving suggestions to import missing value from somewhere even Astro extension added.

change settings to

```js
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
 "source.organizeImports": "never" // or false
}
```